# How to implement iText onto build gradle

Tags: android, gradle, itext

I am trying to add iText library 7.1.3 onto the app build.gradle for my project.

I add the implementation onto my dependency on the app build.gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.1.3'
}
```

This error pops up when I build on the activity.

```
"Error: MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)"
```

I need to implement this library onto my project.

Comment: You should to change your `minSdkVersion` to 26.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: In your `build.gradle` file replace `minSdkVersion YOUR_VERSION` to `minSdkVersion 26`

Comment: Can you attach you `build.gradle` file?

Comment: That error mentioned earlier does not pop up anymore now it's "More than one file was found with OS independent path 'com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/HYSMyeongJoStd-Medium.properties' ".....btw how do I attach a file on here? Sorry, but I am new here :/

Comment: Just post code of your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hecto.finaltest"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }   
}

    dependencies {
         implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.1.4'
    }

Comment: Did you try to replace `minSdkVersion 22` to `minSdkVersion 26`?

Comment: Yes but the phone on which I am testing my app is API 22. Also when I put package option>remove>  'com/itextpdf/whatever' the app builds but then another file is said to be found with OS independent path. I am going crazzyyyyy what must I do.

Comment: If you want to use `'com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.1.3'` library, then you need to set minSdkVersion 26 and it will work only on phones which 26 and above. Or refuse this library.